# How to tell whether a URL is a Facebook Page or Profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I use FQL to validate whether a user-submitted URL is a Facebook Page or Profile as seen here: [Validate a Facebook page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175081/validate-a-facebook-page-url)

This previously worked. When I'd send a URL like facebook.com/zuck or facebook.com/cocacola it would return a normalized_url with profile.php or /pages/. Now, it just returns the same URL: e.g. facebook.com/zuck.

Is this a Facebook API bug? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use the Facebook Graph API and look for properties that only a page would have. For example the Coca Cola API return (see below) returns `likes` which only a page would have, you could also look for a `description`, `website`, `about` and `location` but don't rely on just one. Conversely, a person will tend to have a `first_name` and `last_name`. Use these in unison to determine whether the username is a person or page.

http://graph.facebook.com/zuck

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

```
{
   "id": "40796308305",
   "name": "Coca-Cola",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174560_40796308305_2093137831_s.jpg",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
   "likes": 41519873,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "10150682306963306",
      "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/416803_10150682306963306_40796308305_9337341_812683101_n.jpg",
      "offset_y": 0
   },
   "category": "Food/beverages",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "http://www.coca-cola.com",
   "username": "coca-cola",
   "founded": "1886",
   "description": "Created in 1886 in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was first offered as a fountain beverage at Jacob's Pharmacy by mixing Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water. \n\nCoca-Cola was patented in 1887, registered as a trademark in 1893 and by 1895 it was being sold in every state and territory in the United States. In 1899, The Coca-Cola Company began franchised bottling operations in the United States. \n\nCoca-Cola might owe its origins to the United States, but its popularity has made it truly universal. Today, you can find Coca-Cola in virtually every part of the world.",
   "about": "The Coca-Cola Facebook Page is a collection of your stories showing how people from around the world have helped make Coke into what it is today.",
   "location": {
      "latitude": 53.71282619,
      "longitude": -1.51214516
   },
   "checkins": 92,
   "talking_about_count": 383754
}
```

Comment: Understand it's very late but just wanted to thank you for this solution. Finally getting around to implementing now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem and I've decided to watch the "is_published" or "likes" fields.