# Validiting encoded facebook url

Tags: html, facebook, xhtml, w3c-validation, xhtml-transitional

A DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional document contains the following example of encoded url linked to facebook page

`https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=//////////////&skip_api_login=1&display=popup&social_plugin=like&external_page_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FSome-Name%2F237492089634567&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fuiserver.php%3F ethod%3Dopt.inlike%26app_id%3D127760087287645%26display%3Dpopup%26social_plugin%3Dlike%26secure%3Dfalse%26protocol%3Dhttp%253A%26external_page_url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fpages%252FSome-Name%252F567892089644210%26from_login%3D1%26client_id%3D12773257237610&rcount=1`

which is not validated by html validation tool provided by service provider like W3C

I read a post at [Validate a Facebook page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175081/validate-a-facebook-page-url)

Shall I follow this guideline in order to validate the link?

Is there any other alternative available for the same purpose?

Comment: Just convert every `&` into `&amp;` … that’s an absolute basic HTML syntax rule, btw.

Comment: The document has now been validated. Thanks a lot!