# Validating a Facebook Link in PHP

Tags: php

I want to check my input link is vaild.
But how can I ?
I was set check method for email:
See my php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(1500);




$pp->sendEmailTo('email@google.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

How can I check valid my url (facebook) ?
Like: `$validator->field('facebook')->isWebsite();`

Comment: What framework is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate a Facebook page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175081/validate-a-facebook-page-url)